# OpenVPN clients have no connectivity over IPv6

Tags: openvpn, ipv6, tomato

I'm trying to add IPv6 tunnel support to a OpenVPN server (i.e. clients can access the IPv6 internet through VPN).

The router that runs OpenVPN (Netgear WNDR4500v1 running Tomato v1.28-140) has IPv6 through Hurricane Electric (both a routed /64 and a routed /48)
    - 2001:xxxx:7:3b3::2 is the WAN IPv6 address
    - 2001:xxxx:8:3b3::1/64 is routed to the LAN interface (br0)
    - 2001:xxxx:e1ca::/48 is routed to the OpenVPN interface (tun21)

IPv6 works from the LAN, test-ipv6.com returns 10/10.

I can connect from a client to the OpenVPN server over IPv4 or IPv6, and the client gets a v6 address that's in the 2001:xxxx:e1ca::/48 prefix. However, the client has no IPv6 connectivity at all. I've tried this with multiple clients (Tunnelblick/macOS, OpenVPN for Android, OpenVPN Connect/iOS). test-ipv6.com says "No IPv6 address detected". Also, this shows up in the server logs:

```
SM-N910V/2610:xxxx:7f97 MULTI: bad source address from client [2610:xxxx:7f97], packet dropped
```

I've looked at the [OpenVPN IPv6 wiki](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/IPv6), as well as [Jacob D Evans' guide](https://www.jacobdevans.com/ipv6-openvpn-tunneling-with-asus-merlinwrt/), among other resources. The server/client configs are below.

Server config:

```
# Automatically generated configuration
daemon
server 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
proto udp
port 1194
dev tun21
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo adaptive
keepalive 15 60
verb 3
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.1"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
tls-auth static.key 0
ca ca.crt
dh dh.pem
cert server.crt
key server.key
status-version 2
status status

# Custom Configuration
proto udp6

topology subnet
push "topology subnet"

server-ipv6 2001:xxxx:e1ca::/64
push "route-ipv6 2001:xxxx:8:3b3::/64"
push "route-ipv6 2001:xxxx:e1ca::/48"

push "comp-lzo adaptive"
verb 4

auth sha256
```

Client config:

```
client
dev tun

remote vpn.server.com 1194 udp6
float
nobind

persist-key
persist-tun

remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
key-direction 1
auth sha256

explicit-exit-notify
comp-lzo adaptive
pull

<ca>...</ca>
<cert>...</cert>
<key>...</key>
<tls-auth>...</tls-auth>
```

`ip -6 route` before connecting to the VPN:

```
2001:xxxx:7:3b3::2 via fe80::6c5:a4ff:feea:9cc1 dev enp0s3 proto static metric 100 pref medium
2610:xxxx::/64 dev enp0s3 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
fe80::6c5:a4ff:feea:9cc1 dev enp0s3 proto static metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp0s3 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp0s3 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::6c5:a4ff:feea:9cc1 dev enp0s3 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
```

`ip -6 route` after connecting to the VPN:

```
2001:xxxx:7:3b3::2 via fe80::6c5:a4ff:feea:9cc1 dev enp0s3 proto static metric 100 pref medium
2001:xxxx:8:3b3::/64 via 2001:xxxx:e1ca::1 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 pref medium
2001:xxxx:e1ca::1 dev tun0 proto kernel metric 50 pref medium
2001:xxxx:e1ca::1 dev tun0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2001:xxxx:e1ca::1000 dev tun0 proto kernel metric 50 pref medium
2001:xxxx:e1ca::/48 via 2001:xxxx:e1ca::1 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 pref medium
2610:xxxx::/64 dev enp0s3 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
fe80::6c5:a4ff:feea:9cc1 dev enp0s3 proto static metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp0s3 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp0s3 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default dev tun0 proto static metric 50 pref medium
default via fe80::6c5:a4ff:feea:9cc1 dev enp0s3 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
```

`ip -6 route` after running the commands posted by @grawity below:

```
default from 2001:xxxx:e1ca::/64 dev tun0 metric 1024 pref medium
default from 2610:xxxx::/64 via 2610:xxxx::1 dev enp0s3 metric 1024 pref medium
2001:xxxx:7:3b3::2 via fe80::6c5:a4ff:feea:9cc1 dev enp0s3 proto static metric 100 pref medium
2001:xxxx:8:3b3::/64 via 2001:xxxx:e1ca::1 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 pref medium
2001:xxxx:e1ca::1 dev tun0 proto kernel metric 50 pref medium
2001:xxxx:e1ca::1 dev tun0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2001:xxxx:e1ca::1000 dev tun0 proto kernel metric 50 pref medium
2001:xxxx:e1ca::/48 via 2001:xxxx:e1ca::1 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 pref medium
2610:xxxx::/64 dev enp0s3 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
fe80::6c5:a4ff:feea:9cc1 dev enp0s3 proto static metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp0s3 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp0s3 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default dev tun0 proto static metric 50 pref medium
default via fe80::6c5:a4ff:feea:9cc1 dev enp0s3 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
```

Anybody have any ideas as to what is going on?

OpenVPN logs: https://gist.github.com/abraha2d/f339ff163dd93e20ba3b499c69d6abe3

Comment: So the OV server is able to communicate via IPv6, but not the client? - Have any IPv6 addresses been assigned to the client machine, and is the client machine dual-stack (_ie_: IPv4 and IPv6)? Also, do you have (IPv6) packet routing disabled in the router configuration, as this can prevent networked machines from being able to communicate with each other via IPv6 packets?

Comment: @YTreehuggerCymru The client is being assigned an IPv6 address by the OpenVPN server (2001:xxxx:e1ca::1000). The client is definitely dual stack, as IPv6 works fine outside the VPN (according to test-ipv6.com). IPv6 routing is enabled in the router config.

Comment: All that comes to mind, then, are issues related to local networks: OpenVPN is an absolute something unmentionable in relation to these, and I had to switch to a 10.200.0 subnet because my implementation of OV would not play nice with 192.168 subnets.

Comment: @YTreehuggerCymru I figured IPv6 wouldn't have such issues, since addresses are unique everywhere. My gut tells me the `MULTI: bad source address` is the key to solving this. Maybe some configuration detail I'm overlooking?

Comment: Do you have a plain Linux client available, and can you test on it with some additional routes manually added _after_ establishing the connection? (Connect, then add `ip route add ::/0 from 2001:xxxx:e1ca::/64 dev tun0` *and* `ip route add ::/0 from 2610:xxx/64 via <langw> dev eth0`.)

Comment: On the second command, i substituted `2610:xxxx::1` for `<langw>`, and `enp0s3` instead of `eth0`. Didn't change anything, IPv6 still doesn't work.

Comment: @grawity I've updated the question with the routes before/after connecting to the VPN

Comment: Going back over your original question, I am beginning to think that this is not related to OV at all: test-ipv6.com says "No IPv6 address detected" says to me that you might have an underlying network issue (probably in the router configuration bearing in mind the variety of clients you have used for testing). Are you able to provide any details of your router's IPv6 configuration?

Comment: @YTreehuggerCymru The router running OpenVPN has Tomato Shibby v1.28-140 installed. I've put the HE IPv6 tunnel details into the Basic IPv6 page. I use the VPN Tunneling > OpenVPN Server page to configure OpenVPN, which generates the config file above. I had to add `ip6tables -I INPUT 1 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT` to the Firewall tab of Scripts, since the OpenVPN gui doesn't take of that. Can't really think of anything else that's non-standard from a default Tomato install. What other details are needed?

Comment: I currently use Draytek (proprietory, no DD-WRT or custom), but what you have done looks good, so, in my case and as a last resort, I would resort to "Hello World" and build-on; ie: drop all firewalls and similar and go for an absolutely basic connection (using IPv6) and go from there. If that still fails you have, at least, eliminated a lot of possibilities

Comment: These are my absolute basics snippets for IPv4 (not sure of IPv6 config, yet, so I will look that up and test later), but it should be simple to change them:

// dev tun
remote 10.200.0.6
ifconfig 10.200.0.1 10.200.0.2
secret static.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-tun
persist-key

// dev tun
remote 10.200.0.5
ifconfig 10.200.0.2 10.200.0.1
user nobody
group nobody
secret static.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-tun
persist-key

Comment: @YTreehuggerCymru Do you think it would make any difference if I moved the OV server to a machine inside the LAN? That way I can use the latest version and such, and I have greater control over the configuration. The machine would be running Linux. I guess all I would need to do is to port-forward 1194/tcp, and route a /64 as well. I could probably recreate your config exactly and see if that works.

Comment: My apologies for not being back in touch (campaign work is keeping me busier than I would have liked). I think that moving your configuration away from the router to a machine to machine configuration is definitely something that you should try (I have often found that router implementations have odd functionality, do not behave as expected, or need specific parameters to make them behave as expected, plus the libraries will be firmware dependent and may, thus, be out-of-date). The code I have given you should work for IPv4 and a newer algorithm may now be available.

Comment: To create the static key (linux, command line): openvpn --genkey --secret static.key ...and an observation of my own, regarding IP addresses: the two _ifconfig_ IP addresses that OV will use on establishing a connection are not configured on my router, and there is absolutely no need for me to reconfigure my router at all in order to allow their use, as they are part of the same 255.255.255.0 subnet as the other two 10.200.0 addresses (10.200.0.5 and 10.200.0.6), so OpenVPN is allowed to use them via the OpenVPN adapter and DHCP.

Comment: The key with this is getting a basic setup going that can then be made to work as IPv6, not just IPv4, and then adding-in your requirements for what you want, testing along the way to see where things break. At that point you will hopefully be able to identify exactly what has broken what, and where, and be able to fix it; following which the configuration can be moved back onto the router, at which point you will know for definite whether your router, as opposed to machine, configuration is causing a problem.

Comment: @YTreehuggerCymru I shall do that, and update here how it goes.

Comment: Fair enough, - I haven't forgotten about this, either.

Comment: @YTreehuggerCymru Finally got time to look into this some more. I set up an OpenVPN server on a Linux machine inside the LAN. Everything works now, IPv4 goes out via the router (added static route on the router for the OpenVPN subnet), and IPv6 goes out via a Hurricane Electric tunnel. Looks like there's some issue with the dd-wrt version of OpenVPN.

Comment: *tomato, not dd-wrt.

Comment: Good, - well done, - I had been trying to work things out on my side, but my setup does not like IPv6 (like yourself, a router configuration issue); hence the reason why I had not been able to update you with anything.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a push option in your server configuration.

You have:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

You need to also have the `ipv6` option, i.e.:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 ipv6"
```

Comment: I tried with/without the `push "redirect-gateway def1 ipv6"` option. No change.